# dse pig datetime functions

Tags: apache-pig, datastax

Can someone give a full example of date time functions including the 'register' jar ? I have been trying to get CurrentTime() and ToDate() running without much success. I have the piggybank jar in classpath and registered the same. But it always says the function has to be defined before usage.
I read this question [comparing datetime in pig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764761/comparing-datetime-in-pig) before this.

Answer (score 1):

Datetime functions can be easily implemented using native pig, you no need to go for piggybank jar.

**Example:**
In this example i will read set of dates from the input file, get the current datetime and calculate the total no of days between previous and current date

**input.txt**

```
2014-10-12T10:20:47
2014-08-12T10:20:47
2014-07-12T10:20:47
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' AS (mydate:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ToDate(mydate) AS prevDate,CurrentTime() AS currentDate,DaysBetween(CurrentTime(),ToDate(mydate)) AS diffDays;
DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
(2014-10-12T10:20:47.000+05:30, 2014-12-12T10:39:15.455+05:30, 61)
(2014-08-12T10:20:47.000+05:30, 2014-12-12T10:39:15.455+05:30, 122)
(2014-07-12T10:20:47.000+05:30, 2014-12-12T10:39:15.455+05:30, 153)
```

You can refer few examples from my old post
[Human readable String date converted to date using Pig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26933900/human-readable-string-date-converted-to-date-using-pig/26935915#26935915)
[Storing Date and Time In PIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995887/storing-date-and-time-in-pig/26008077#26008077)
[how to convert UTC time to IST using pig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777499/how-to-convert-utc-time-to-ist-using-pig/26943408#26943408)